# How many degrees of freedom for the spin 1/2?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, degrees-of-freedom

I count four but most of the documentation I read, says just one.

1) One degree of freedom for the spin measurement outcome, either up or down.

3) three degrees of freedom for the unit quaternion representing the orientation of the spin in space.

Is this correct, or have I made a mistake?

Comment: Number of components (degrees of freedom) for a particle with spin j = 2j+1. Put j=1/2

Comment: @Avantgarde But then, how do you explain that the spin can be oriented differently in space?

Comment: Yes, spin can be oriented in an arbitrary direction, say, z direction. Now, the number of independent states that you can get in that one z direction, is 2j+1. For a spin half particle, for example, you get two independent states: $m=+\frac{1}{2}$ and $m=-\frac{1}{2}$. Coordinate system is just a labelling system. What we really want to know (degrees of freedom) comes about from calculating the number of independent bases of the underlying abstract vector space of the state

Comment: @Avantgarde Consider the case of a system with two spins. The orientation of the first one defines the axis. Then the second spin can be oriented in any direction. Surely, the additional rotational possibilities of the second spin are added as additional degrees of freedom to the system? A system where each spins are equi-oriented must be different that one where each spins have a different orientation? In other words, you need more independent numbers to define differently orientated spins, then equi-oriented ones?

Comment: But how can one system have two spins? For a state, $J^2$ and $J_z$ commute, and therefore characterize the state completely. Are you talking about adding the momenta of 2 separate systems and obtaining the momentum of the resulting composite system?

Comment: @avantgarde Sorry. I mean a system with two qubits represented physically by two particles with spin-1/2. One is oriented by the axis while the other can be oriented in an arbitrary orientation with respect to the first one.

Comment: What do you mean, *precisely*, by "degree of freedom"?

Comment: @emilio the quantity of real numbers required to describe the system

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay That would mean that a particle in one dimension (both in QM as well as in classical Liouvillian mechanics) would have infinite degrees of freedom - is that a definition you're willing to stick to? The definition of DOF can be pretty tricky in quantum mechanics, and pretending that you can use the exact same language to describe continuum systems as well as finite-dimensional ones with a one-size-fits-all system is fundamentally just kidding oneself.

Comment: @Emilio >That would mean that a particle in one dimension would have infinite degrees of freedom. - You just need 6 real numbers to describe that.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay No, that is incorrect - the wavefunction lives in an infinite-dimensional vector space, and you require a countably infinite (if you use e.g. the harmonic-oscillator basis) tuple of real numbers to describe it. This isn't anywhere near controversial - but if you're not comfortable with that basic fact of quantum mechanics, maybe it's best to leave spin on the back burner until you are.

Comment: @Emilio Are you talking about the arbitrary case where every point could potentially have a different value than any other point? Because if you start with a simple ideal system (e.g. a free particle), the value at all of these points is derivable from the ideal system. Hence you only need a handful of real numbers to describe the ideal system. These are the degrees of freedom. (Thanks for the answer below btw).

Comment: @Alexandre (*sigh*) no, it's *not* derivable from any "ideal" system, whatever that means. There are an infinite number of independent states, and no finite number of real numbers will suffice to specify the state of the system. This is standard material, explained in any introductory textbook, and it is nowhere near controversial. If you just don't want to accept it, though,  that's ultimately up to you.

Comment: @Emilio The answer there would appear to contradict what you are saying. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154563/degrees-of-freedom-in-quantum-mechanics I promise I am not trying to be difficult, I just want to rule out the possibility where we might be talking about slightly different things.

Comment: No, it doesn't - it *also* shows that your definition of DOF is not useful in QM. There's just no useful way of counting DOFs that will be meaningful for both continuum DOFs (as in that answer) and for finite-dimensional systems (as in your question). Seriously, there's no substitute for a long, hard session with a textbook.

Comment: @Emilio I think you are confusing state space with degrees of freedom. A particle on a 1D line has 1 degree of freedom - the real number describing its position along the axis. However, it could be at any position, hence the state space is infinite.

Comment: No, *you* are confusing dimensionality of state space with degrees of freedom - see [your definition above](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/332968#comment746361_332968) . I would hope that you can now see why there is no unified way to define DOFs in QM (classical DOFs have infinite state space, while spin has finite-dimenional state space) but there is thin evidence that you're willing to listen, so I'm pretty much out of this conversation.

Comment: @Emilio Its implied that redundant numbers don't count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the strict definition for 'number of degrees of freedom' you've given in the comments,

> the quantity of real numbers required to describe the system,

then a spin-1/2 particle has **two** degrees of freedom if it is in a pure state. The general state of such a particle can be written as
$$
|\psi⟩ = \cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)\left|↑ \right>+e^{i\varphi}\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)\left|↓\right>,
$$
where $\left|↑ \right>$ and $\left|↓\right>$ are eigenstates of the $z$ component of the spin vector. Here the state is parametrized in terms of the two real parameters $\theta$ and $\varphi$, which essentially parametrize the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) - the natural manifold representation of the state space of the particle.

More importantly, this number is derived as the manifold dimension of $\mathbb C\mathrm P^2$, the complex projective space of dimension $2$, which is essentially the complex vector space $\mathbb C^2$ (the two-complex-dimensional vector space of all the complex linear combinations of $\left|↑ \right>$ and $\left|↓\right>$, so four real dimensions), with one taken out by the fixed normalization and one taken out by the irrelevance of the global phase. More generally, a particle of spin $j$ has a $(2j+1)$-complex-dimensional state space, and therefore can be described using $4j$ real numbers.

---

That said, the definition you've given is essentially meaningless, and it is essentially incapable of describing systems as simple as a massive spinless particle on a 1D line; there the Hilbert state space is infinite-dimensional (spanned e.g. by the harmonic-oscillator basis) and you absolutely need an infinite number of real numbers to describe any state of the system. Moreover, the same is true in Liouvillian classical mechanics for the same situation.

What that really means is that the term "degree of freedom" is not a particularly useful concept in a quantum mechanical situation, particularly where you might have a finite-dimensional system coupled to an infinite-dimensional one (as you might e.g. in the hugely popular [Jaynes-Cummings model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaynes%E2%80%93Cummings_model) and its plethora of generalizations). In the situations where you do need to keep track of such things, you end up needing to specify the types of systems (i.e. the dimension of their state spaces) and their number, and there just isn't a single bag where you can chuck everything in and get a meaningful number.

You find any of that unpalatable? Well, join the back of the queue.